In the RDF plot of a particular orbital, why don't peaks come with radius greater than that of the max peak?
While studying radial distribution function (RDF) plots I see that orbitals (3s, 2s, ... 3p etc) often  have peaks at radii less than that of the maximum peak. Assuming the probability of finding an e- is nonzero everywhere (except at the nucleus) why don't further peaks appear at radii greater than the maximum?


Because that is what the spherical harmonics look like - the higher the order (say 3 in 3s) the more nodes there are, but there are only a specific number.

One of reasons is that P(r) =4.pi.r^2 . |Psi(r)|^2

It's okay for me for the number of radial or angular/conical nodes. But why the no of nodes gets restricted before the peak? Is it anything related to the energy an e in a specific energy can be restricted to Energy? I am asking for a mathematical proof of the above mentioned.

The number of peaks is iirc related to the order of Laguerre orthogonal polynomials involved in the radial part of the wave function.

It's a reasonable question but please try editing it to make it more clear, in particular the first sentence (I tried but then gave up). The question is, why there are no peaks at radii greater than the maximum in the RDF.

Yes I meant that only .....

Why not to perform mathematical analysis of wave function for n=3, l=0 , including recalculation to radial probability from probability density?

The RDF is zero at the nodes, too.

Yes but what truly limits the possibility for an e of a  orbital to gain peak with increasing orbital energy(increasing x axis or more clearly radii on the graph)? That I can't find. With the radial function eqn I can find the radius and all that... But guys even if I integrate and find the radial probability how to find why the electron is limited with increasing radii??

The number of peaks in the RDF is equal to n-l (n,l being the principal and angular quantum numbers). But your question is why $\psi \to 0$ as $r \to \inf$??

Partially yes, it was like if the no of peaks formula was not taken into consideration why is it that the probability does not gain a non zero peak with radii greater than Rmax as it —> infinity. I just wanted a proper theoretical (with mathematics if possible ) answer rather than prevalent formulas.

Though I feel it has something to do with energy. Since energy of the system is fixed unless the body gains energy the energy is quantized. But why can't it gain atleast a min. Non zero peak? What exactly restricts it and why does the peaks follow the trend increasing then rapid decrease and not slow change in probability with radii
